# Given real numbers $a, b, c, u, v, w$ solve the linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This problem is taken from Titu Andreescu's book *Essential Linear Algebra with Applications: A Problem-Solving Approach* and it states:

Given real numbers a,b,c,u,v,w solve the linear system:
$$ax-by=u$$
$$by-cz=v$$
$$-ax+cz=w$$

What I have so far is, using the Rouché-Capelli theorem the system only has solutions if rank(A)=rank(A|b). I've already calculated rank(A)<3 given that A is non-invertible as $det(A)=0$. Therefore using the determinant of submatrices, $rank(A)=2$ when $ab\neq 0$ or when $bc\neq 0$. Now I can proceed to checking the rank of A|b. Manipulating the original equations I get the result $u+v+w=0$. When obtaining the determinant of A|b to see if it's invertible, I replace one of the columns of A and it gives me an equation that contains the latter identity. Therefore $rank(A|b)<3$. Now I can easily find a 2x2 submatrix that is invertible given $ab\neq0$ or $bc\neq0$. From here I don't know how to proceed in obtaining the solution to the system now that I know one such exists.

Comment: I don't see how this could be done,but I am open to changing my method @Moo

Comment: What I get is $$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}  1 & 0 & \frac{-c}{a} & \frac{u+v}{a} \\  0 & a & \frac{-c}{a} & \frac{v}{b} \\  -0 & 0 & 0 & w+v+u \\ \end{array} \right)
$$ But I don't really see how this helps me, sorry if I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Meaning that I can write $x=\frac{zc+u+v}{a}$, $y=\frac{v+cz}{b}$and z a free variable for v,c,u,a,b$\in \mathbb{R}$  and $a,b\neq0$?

Answer (score 1):

Combining the 1st and 2nd eqn's gives 
$ax - cz = u + v.$

However, from the 3rd eqn, you know that 
$ax - cz = -w.$

Therefore, unless you are allowed to assume that 
$u + v = -w$ the problem can't have a general solution.

That is, the above analysis proves that if you are given 
specific values for $u,v,w$ such that it is not the case that 
$u + v = -w$ then no satisfying values for $x, y, z$ can exist.